# Where are the Silver Doors in the Labyrinth?

Tags: path-of-exile

I've found a few silver keys in the labyrinth, and Izaro says that 'where there are silver keys, there are silver doors'. Is the door going to be found in the same room as the key or will it be further in the labyrinth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doors are usually in different rooms then the keys. Check the panels next to the entrances and exits from the zones.

Comment: When you check the panel, you will see that in the room you are, you will see an icon of a silver door.